# How to display different value from the api on radio button click in react js.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, radio-button, buttonclick

I have a radio button component and iam mapping api data to it what i want is whenever an option is selected my website should display some data let say some kind of description text the problem is the data does not change on button click it remains the same for every option selected.

This is my radio button and p tag below is where text is to be displayed

```
<input
type="radio"
title="giftCard"
value={this.state.giftCard}
name={this.props.giftDetails.variations.map(
       (e) => e.reward_text 
     )}
   onChange={(e) => {
      this.setState({ giftCard: e.target.value });
       }}
                           
    onClick={() => {
      this.props.giftDetails.variations.map(
      (e) => this.setState({ giftDescription: e.reward_description })
            )
         }}
                            
 />
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: giftDescription}}/>
```

my api respone is

```
"variations": [
          {
            "variation_id": 1,
            "variation_name": "210kr",
            "price": "210",
            "reward_text": "200kr. Price",
            "reward_description": "Med et gavekort til Sendentanke.dk kan du vælge mellem gavekort til hundredevis af butikker og oplevelser ét sted."
          },
          {
            "variation_id": 2,
            "variation_name": "400kro",
            "price": "400",
            "reward_text": "400 Price",
            "reward_description": "Earn a reward"
          }
        ],
```

[You can see in the picture how radio buttons are added and how text is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOjuG.png)

Comment: Add checked attribute to input type like `checked={this.props.giftDetails.variations.filter(v =>v.variation_name === this.state.giftCard) }` something like this.

Comment: i have tried it but my text doesnt change with iti want to display reward description you can see in the response above.

Comment: @ShankarGaneshJayaraman i want to set the reward description according to the button click of radio component what i want is to display reward_description according to the selected reward_text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `onclick` since you can handle the setState with `onChange` itself also use `checked` attribute for radio button and generate the radio buttons through iteration like below.

```js
const Options = this.props.giftDetails.variations.map((v) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={v.variation_id}>
          <input
            type="radio"
            value={v.variation_id}
            checked={v.variation_id == this.state.giftCard}
            onChange={(e) => {
              this.setState({
                giftCard: e.target.value,
                giftDescription: v.reward_description,
              });
            }}
          />
          {v.reward_text}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    });

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {Options}
        <p>{this.state. giftDescription}</p>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
```

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { giftCard: null, giftDescription: null };
  }

  render() {
    console.log("this.state", this.state);
    const variants = {
      variations: [
        {
          variation_id: 1,
          variation_name: "210kr",
          price: "210",
          reward_text: "200kr. Price",
          reward_description:
            "Med et gavekort til Sendentanke.dk kan du vælge mellem gavekort til hundredevis af butikker og oplevelser ét sted.",
        },
        {
          variation_id: 2,
          variation_name: "400kro",
          price: "400",
          reward_text: "400 Price",
          reward_description: "Earn a reward",
        },
      ],
    };

    const Options = variants.variations.map((v) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <input
            key={v.variation_id}
            type="radio"
            value={v.variation_id}
            checked={v.variation_id == this.state.giftCard}
            onChange={(e) => {
              this.setState({
                giftCard: e.target.value,
                giftDescription: v.reward_description,
              });
            }}
          />
          {v.reward_text}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    });

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {Options}
        <p>{this.state.giftDescription}</p>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for solving the problem @Shankar but the checked prop is not working it is not checked by default i want 1 option to be checked by default

Comment: if you know default variant id upfront then assign in `constructor()` with `this.state = { giftCard: 1, giftDescription: null };` also,  you can set the state dynamically with Rect lifecycle method `ComponentDidMount()`

Comment: how can i set it to checked and display the `giftDescription` of that option

Comment: you can set both the states before rendering using `componentDidMount() {}` inside this method fetch the API with default id and set the state for card and description.